# How to install the ia32-libs in a 64-bit Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I wanna to install the ia32-libs in my linux mint, but when i use `apt-get` ,it told me sth like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gconf2 : Depends: gconf-service (= 3.2.6-1)
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-i386
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.17)
 libgconf2-4 : Depends: libgconf-2-4 (= 3.2.6-1) but 3.2.6-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

is the locales package broken? then i use `apt-get -f install`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dh-apparmor emacs23-bin-common emacs23-common emacs23-common-non-dfsg fonts-texgyre html2text language-pack-zh-hans language-pack-zh-hans-base latex-beamer latex-xcolor libimobiledevice2
  libkrb5-dev libusbmuxd1 pgf prosper ps2eps systemtap-common systemtap-runtime tex-gyre texlive-extra-utils texlive-font-utils texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended-doc
  texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-recommended-doc texlive-pstricks texlive-pstricks-doc tipa ttf-marvosym
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gconf-service gconf2-common libgconf-2-4 locales
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gconf-service-backend language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base language-pack-gnome-zh-hans language-pack-gnome-zh-hans-base ubuntu-minimal
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gconf-service gconf2-common libgconf-2-4 locales
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 to remove and 1576 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,679 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,895 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  locales gconf-service libgconf-2-4 gconf2-common
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 219432 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace locales 2.13+git20120306-9 (using .../locales_2.17-92_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement locales ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.17-92_all.deb (--unpack):
 **trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/validlocale', which is also in package libc-bin 2.17-0ubuntu5**
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.17-92_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

is there any method to solve this problem ?

Comment: Not sure about your issue, as I'm not an apt user, but it seems you have a ton of stuff that was installed as dependencies to other stuff. You can get rid of it all with `apt-get autoremove`. Run it every once and a while to clean up your system.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this in your terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Please note this worked for me at that time. May not be working now as it's been 5 years now I posted this answer.

Comment: Error: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate

Comment: Check Mike's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182765/how-to-install-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is going install ia32-libs in ubuntu versions later to raring, here is the process:

```
sudo -i
apt-get install gksu 
dpkg --add-architecture i386
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list
apt-get update
apt-get install ia32-libs
rm ia32-libs-raring.list
```

For latest Linux Mint's there's no need to install this, it's preinstalled there...

Answer (score -1):

You can install them with this command:

> sudo apt install bluez-alsa:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:i386
>   gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 gtk2-engines:i386
>   gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 gtk2-engines-oxygen:i386
>   gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 gvfs:i386 ibus-gtk:i386 libacl1:i386
>   libaio1:i386 libao4:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
>   libasyncns0:i386 libattr1:i386 libaudio2:i386
>   libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libcap2:i386 libcapi20-3:i386
>   libcups2:i386 libcupsimage2:i386 libcurl3:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386
>   libesd0:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgail-common:i386
>   libgconf-2-4:i386 libgdbm3:i386 libgettextpo0:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386
>   libglu1-mesa:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port10:i386
>   libgtk2.0-0:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libncursesw5:i386 libnspr4:i386
>   libnss3:i386 libodbc1:i386 libopenal1:i386
>   libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386 libpulsedsp:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386
>   libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-qt3support:i386
>   libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-scripttools:i386 libqt4-sql:i386
>   libqt4-svg:i386 libqt4-test:i386 libqt4-xml:i386
>   libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtgui4:i386
>   libqtwebkit4:i386 librsvg2-common:i386 libsane:i386
>   libsdl-image1.2:i386 libsdl-mixer1.2:i386 libsdl-net1.2:i386
>   libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 libsdl1.2debian:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386
>   libssl0.9.8:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libstdc++5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
>   libxaw7:i386 libxml2:i386 libxp6:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386
>   libxtst6:i386 odbcinst1debian2:i386 xaw3dg:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
>   libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libpam-winbind:i386

Package:arch is the apt format.However arch is optional.