# error while installing ia32-libs

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install "ia32-libs" After doing google I did following steps. Yet not able to do it...

1st step i have added dpkg --add-architecture i386
2nd step added "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list"

```
root@user:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
root@user:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list
root@user:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get update
Ign http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring InRelease 
Ign http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release   
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources          
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources      
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages   
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages    
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Raring is an old non-LTS release. Its support lifetime ended 6 months ago and packages for it are no longer on archive.ubuntu.com.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Try these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
sudo -i
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list
apt-get update
apt-get install ia32-libs
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ia32-libs-raring.list
apt-get update
exit
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

Reference: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182765/how-to-install-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts).

Comment: Thanks for help I didn't get change to try your code. but following steps helped me to solved this.