# Error installing lib32stdc++6 on ubuntu 14.10 on a 64bit OS

Tags: android, regex, ubuntu

While installing android studio on ubuntu, I am getting error

> could not run mksdcard SDK tool

I found out that I need to install lib32stdc++6. But executing

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

is giving following error:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package lib32stdc++6
>   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32stdc++6'

I want to know that how do we install a 32 bit library on a 64 bit OS. Thanks :D

Comment: Did you try this [SO Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182765/how-to-install-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr)?

Comment: did you solved this ?

Comment: Yup, But I would suggest  to use version 14.04 or 15.04 because 14.10 has reached the end of its life. :D