# Error connecting to download server on install Appcelerator Studio

Tags: ubuntu, titanium, appcelerator

[image]

This is the same error posted here: https://community.appcelerator.com/topic/3021/installing-on-ubuntu-14-04

I installed:

`oracle-jdk6
nodejs and nodejs-legacy`

Using

`appcelerator x64`

on a Ubuntu 14.04 (specs in attatchment)

also ran:

`sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
echo 'export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/mozilla' >> ~/.bashrc`

and tried:

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` but this didn't work and instead I used this:

`sudo -i
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list
apt-get update
apt-get install ia32-libs`

which I found here: [How to install ia32-libs in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182765/how-to-install-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr)

Thank you

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Linux systems require the GTK windowing system, Node.js, and the JDK to be installed before running Studio. So make it compatible with this link

- https://platform.appcelerator.com/#/product/cli
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Then install CLI using the following command

- sudo npm install -g appcelerator
- appc use latest
- appc setup

For CLI command and troubleshooting

1. http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_CLI_Tasks
2. http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_CLI_Troubleshooting

And take a fresh copy of Appcelerator Studio and install it in your machine.
​

- https://web.appcelerator.com/product/studio
  ​

Note: Officially Appcelerator do not have Linux support.

​http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-OperatingSystem
​

Hope this helps.