# Trouble with running binary file on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, binaryfiles

I just want to run a binary file, but when i try to do his using my terminal,its acting weird and i can't figure out what's the problem.

```
rohan@rohan:~$ cd Desktop/
rohan@rohan:~/Desktop$ ls
chal  challenge  __MACOSX
rohan@rohan:~/Desktop$ cd challenge
rohan@rohan:~/Desktop/challenge$ ls
binary1  binary2  binary3
rohan@rohan:~/Desktop/challenge$ ./binary1
bash: ./binary1: Permission denied
rohan@rohan:~/Desktop/challenge$ sudo ./binary1
[sudo] password for rohan: 
sudo: ./binary1: command not found
rohan@rohan:~/Desktop/challenge$
```

I also tried giving it permissions but it still can't execute it. Any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Also , these are the details of the files, My system is a 64-bit, ubuntu 16.04LTS, what would i need to get and how to run this file.

```
file    /home/rohan/Desktop/challenge/binary1
type    EXEC (Executable file)
pic false
has_va  true
root    elf
class   ELF32
lang    c
arch    x86
bits    32
machine Intel 80386
os  linux
subsys  linux
endian  little
strip   false
static  false
linenum true
lsyms   true
relocs  true
rpath   NONE
```

Comment: I think this question should be posted on AskUbuntu

Comment: Please update your question to show the exact error message you got *after* you did the `chmod`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that behavior from a shell script whose first line says to run a program which is not found at that path:

```
#!/bin/nosuchprogram
echo xx
```

also, if the script happens to have carriage-return/line-feed endings, the same result.

If it's a "binary" file, you might start by using the `file` utility to tell what it might be:

```
file binary3
```

and if it happens to be a type which might run on the current system, check with `ldd`, for missing libraries:

```
ldd binary3
```

Likewise, if your Ubuntu system is a 64-bit machine, you may not have libraries to support 32-bit applications.  As a quick check (if you do not know what your system is), the `arch` program tells you what the default architecture is.  Some older systems don't have that, but again `file` is your friend:

```
$ file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0x55f1e005df252708d4c456dcc2c7dccea1006553, stripped
```

(It is possible to have both 32- and 64-bit libraries on Ubuntu, but most are one or the other).

How to get 32-bit applications running on a 64-bit Ubuntu changes slightly from one release to the next.  You may find these helpful:

- [How do I run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit Debian/Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu)
- [How do you run a 32-bit program on a 64-bit version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359156/how-do-you-run-a-32-bit-program-on-a-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu)
- [How to install ia32-libs in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182765/how-to-install-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr)

Comment: i tried doing this, this is what shows up,                                                     rohan@rohan:~/Desktop/challenge$ file binary1
binary1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=43af309d3735b17cef57f70cb997eebafd17ebf2, not stripped
rohan@rohan:~/Desktop/challenge$ ldd binary1
 not a dynamic executable

Comment: I have a 64bit ubuntu system, on running the file command , i got,      rohan@rohan:~/Desktop/challenge$ file binary1
binary1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=43af309d3735b17cef57f70cb997eebafd17ebf2, not stripped
   Now, i don't know what need to installed in order to make it run.